# Why do governments block services while they still can be used via VPN for example?

Tags: vpn

I can open any blocked service in the country I live in via Virtual Private Network (VPN) or proxy servers,so why do governments block services?

**edit**: I think governments do so to make it harder to access the service.. is that the only reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple layers to this seemingly easy question. Your classic restrictive government especially one that has a lot of control can fully cut of external networks outside of their country. A good example of this is what Russia did as a test in 2019 where they achieved this through demands to the countries Internet Service Providers. A full article can be found [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/emmawoollacott/2019/12/24/russia-cuts-off-its-internet-with-mixed-results/?sh=682abfa6619d)

Secondly what you have is a deny by default which is what North Korea and military camps are fond of doing, which is where there are only pre-approved locations for internet users to visit, with everything else being blocked. If the VPN has not been added to the ISP or network egress whitelist then no cigar.

Finally there is a blacklist where you have some IPs/Domain Names/Keywords blocked, however the majority of the internet is allowed. This is common, can be bypassed, but is usually not considered censorship.

Governments may have any number of reasons to block locations on the internet, with not all of this being malicious. The reason why you can circumvent this however is purely due to country internet blocking being outrageously difficult, and even if you vouch for a whitelist approach there can still be exceptions (a common one in China is to create a VPN through Alibaba cloud, and then access services outside the country through one of the approved Alibaba IP addresses). It is worth noting that VPNs are actively working to defeat IP blocking whether this is for watching overseas Netflix, or running Google in China.

For your country in particular, consider the following resources for better understanding of the topic:

- https://afteegypt.org/wp-content/uploads/Egypt-Internet-Censorship-AFTE-OONI-2018-07.pdf
- https://ooni.org/post/egypt-internet-censorship/

(You might need to get your VPN up to view these ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption is part of the reason.

1. It’s hard to block bad sites. There are whole companies (blue coat, zscaler) that are used to block traffic
2. It’s difficult to scan encrypted traffic leaving governments coarse control of blocking (ie, by ip address on a site hosting multiple host names)
3. Some vpn employ technologies to hop around ip addresses or domain names creating a whack a mole situation
4. Corporations use VPNs and most of these companies want other people’s money building stuff in their nation and will support those contractors
5. You can make vpn traffic look like web traffic.
6. IPs are reassigned - for example if you connect to a VPN hosted by AWS and the IP changes every few hours, you have to be ready to unblock those IPs when they are reassigned to another aws site

So it’s technically difficult.

As a policy, is it worth trying to play whack a mole, or just let the small number of people take the risk to use a vpn ?